# Node resolving not-awaited promises in main script

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Why is "timeout' printed by node before terminating when I execute the following code ?

```
const shouldNotPrint = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout')
      resolve('foo')
    }, 300)
  })
}

shouldNotPrint()
console.log('ended')
```

Running the previous code with node 16.13.0 will output

```
> node src/index.js
ended
timeout
```

Is there some kind of top-level await in node waiting for all promises to resolve before ending the process ?

To clarify: I do not want to terminate Node before the end of my promise. I just want to understand, at a low level, the behavior of node and the event-loop in that case. I understand the logic of a timeout + promise and why it would be printed after "ended". The question is why it is displayed at all and why Node is waiting for it to be displayed before terminating the process.

Comment: Well async function is getting called but it waits 0.3 sec to print. In that time other code which is `console.log('ended')` gets executed.

Comment: node has not any top level await .. we can only await inside async function

Comment: From what i can tell, node waits until async routines and timers are finished. If you create a main loop with an interval for example it is not supposed to stop. To force quit without waiting for timers and so on use `process.exit()`.

Comment: Your code isn't waiting for the promise to resolve; node won't end the process as long as there are any scheduled callbacks, waiting to be pushed on the call stack. You can force the node to end the process before the timer expires using `process.exit()`

Comment: The log is guaranteed to show "ended" followed by "timeout" because `console.log('ended')` is called synchronously and `console.log('timeout')` is called some 300 ms later? This will happen whether or not `setTimeout()` is wrapped in `new Promise()`.